# Call colon function with brackets in lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've been researching this for a while with no luck. I want to dynamically call colon function in lua like I do regular functions.

```
obj['functionName']()
```

However the following won't work.

```
obj:['functionName']()
```

is there a work around? Do I have to explicitly add the obj to the function arguments? I'd rather not do the following unless I have to... ie:

```
obj['functionName'](obj)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You probably meant colon (`:`) instead of semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "obj:function()" syntax is (as defined in lua doc) "syntactical sugar" for obj.function(obj), so no, there is no way to bypass this. The syntactic sugar is aimed to a very specific situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `obj:functionName()`, but if by "dynamically" you mean that `functionName` is stored in a variable, then `fn = 'functionName'; obj[fn](obj)` is the only way.

Comment: You probably mean `obj.functionName(obj)`.

Comment: I meant `obj:functionName()` as the OP wanted to avoid specifying `obj` twice; thanks @lhf!